# Nginx MAP Redirect issue

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx

So I have been using NGINX Maps to handle redirects and they are working well. But recently I have discovered a problem, and I can't figure out what is going on for the life of me.

I have three map sections set up that feed into each other via the default.

```
map $host$uri $path_redirects {
    ~*^example.com\/(sample-url-path-)(a|b|c|d)+(\d+|\%.*)$   /$1$2;                                                                       
}

map $host$uri $page_redirects {
    default $path_redirects;
}

map $host$uri$args $redirect_uri {
    default $page_redirects;
    ~*^example.com\/(.*).html(\?PageSpeed.*)$     /$1.html;                                   
}
```

Then I actually redirect based on $redirect_uri. A little confusing, but it helps me keep my redirects organized.

Its been working fine, but Now I have an issue, that I suspect is not related to the map, but I cannot figure out what.

Plugging into regex101.com I can get these rules to match:

(https://regex101.com/r/kgFE7k/1)

(https://regex101.com/r/JLlcZi/2)

But when I have them in my mapping they do not redirect at all. I get a 404.

(redirects) example.com/sample-url-path-c2 
(does not redirect) example.com/sample-url-path-c%23.WYzyrdPyvVo 
(does not redirect) example.com/sample-url-page.html?PageSpeed=noscript

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: So ive found part of the issue. The NGINX $args does not include the '?'. So I had to modify my last map section to be: map $host$uri?$args $redirect_uri {}

Comment: And I fixed the other issue too.

Answer (score 2):

So the issue was my fault. I was able to discover it by 2 things.

One I realized that %23 was actually URL Encoded and was a '#' and not part of the path. Which is why I was not getting a match with %23, but regex101 worked because it treated that as plain text.

Second, the NGINX variable $args does not include the ? from the URL string. So, that matching of the '?' in the regex didn't match it.

To fix I moved both rules to my $args map section and it reads as:

```
map $host$uri?$args $redirect_uri {
    default $page_redirects;
    ~*^example.com\/(.*).html(\?PageSpeed.*)$     /$1.html;
    ~*^example.com\/(sample-url-path-)(a|b|c|d)+(\d+|\#.*|\%.*)$   /$1$2;                                    
}
```

To help others with debugging, it helps to add in debugging headers to your response. In the NGINX config, add in:

```
#DEBUG HEADERS
add_header X-host           "$host" always;
add_header X-uri            "$uri" always;
add_header X-args           "$args" always;
add_header X-full-url       "$host$uri$args" always;
add_header X-redirect-path  "$path_redirects" always;
add_header X-redirect-page  "$page_redirects" always;
add_header X-redirect-uri   "$redirect_uri" always;
```

Change variables to suit. The always part makes NGINX serve it up always, without, it only serves up on some HTTP response codes, but 404 was not one of them.